# Why is my footer appearing at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

Right now my footer is appearing at the top of my page but I'd like it at the bottom, if its rly simple sorry im pretty new to html.

here is my file the css is internal

```css
.middle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/background.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="img/logoanimated.gif" class="middle"></a>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>This website is under construction<br>Copyright &copy; 2022 example.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have the position in the `.middle` class, as fixed, which means it will be on top of everything, so if you change the `position` to relative or some other than fixed, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `position` property to position things. In this case I used fixed to fix the footer at the bottom, then the `inset` property for the shorthand of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties. More on `position`s and how to use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

```css
.middle {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/background.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  inset: auto 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="img/logoanimated.gif" class="middle"></a>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>This website is under construction<br>Copyright &copy; 2022 example.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: TY i just put in the position and inset for it to work but ill definitely take the time to understand it in future

Comment: yeah, they are powerful tools to know in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I gave to footer `position: fixed` `bottom:0` `left:0` and `width:100%` and some sample photos for the background.Also i got footer inside div . I came to this result. I hope it works for you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>title</title>
    <style>
        .middle {
            position: fixed;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        body {
            background-image: url("https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300");
            background-size: cover;
            background-position: center center;
        }

        .footer {
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            left:0; 
            width:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    
        <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300.jpg"
                class="middle"></a>
  
    <div class="footer">
        <p> This website is under construction<br>Copyright &copy; 2022 example.</p>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here try this code, I got rid of the all the css in the `.middle` class, and it centers the image, and puts the footer at the bottom of the image, though you do not want to really ever use fixed position on a footer, because it will always be visible at the bottom, and you don't want that. What you should do, is make is `static`.

As I was looking at your code, the reason why your footer was above everything, is because you made that image fixed, which means everything will flow to start. So think of the `fixed` position this way: Pretend you have two boxes, stacked ontop of each other, then you slide the bottom one all the way out. When you slide the bottom one off, the top one falls in place of the other one. The bottom box had the `fixed` position, so it moves out of place, and it is always in that exact location, even if the window scrolls, it will always in that place, that is why it is called fixed. So just keep that in mind, when you add a `fixed` position to anything, it "raises" it up and everything "flows" underneath it.

```css
.middle {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}

body {
  background-image: url("img/background.webp");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

footer {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>
    <a href="example.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQytQQam75A2ZQMpeZ01oSraB9OHEvBqprjtw&usqp=CAU" class="middle"></a>
  </main>
  <footer>
    <p>This website is under construction<br>Copyright &copy; 2022 example.</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```